# Imagebox with a webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to use an Imagebox on a webform, and not getting the expected results.

I think its something with the path, but not sure. I am new with the path formatting of C# and asp.net.

Code I am trying to use(or have tried to use):

```
T1Pic.ImageUrl = "~/bin/Resources/T1U.jpg";
T1Pic.ImageUrl = "bin\Resources\T1U.jpg";
T1Pic.ImageUrl = "bin\\Resources\\T1U.jpg";
```

Exact path of the image itself:

> C\WebForm\bin\Resources\T1U.jpg

All of the above examples, just give me the generic "dead icon" for the image boxes.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The `bin` directory seems to be a weird place to store images. There may even be a restriction on serving content from there. Try moving your image to somewhere like `C\WebForm\images\T1U.jpg` and make your path `~\images\T1U.jpg`

Comment: @JonP Well that seemed to fix it! I did have to change the filepath to 'T1Pic.ImageUrl = "~\\images\\T1U.jpg";' - but it is all working. Please put a answer up so I can give you proper credit